# Check for sim is available or not in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any api or class to check whether sim is available in the phone . I'm working windows phone silverlight application.

Thanks & Regards,
Pallam Madhukar

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with the current API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SilverLight Application so we can get

DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator

if it returns empty string sim is not available else sim is available.